# Ошибка при установке react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я так понял ошибка совместимости версий, т. к. у меня react@17.0.0. Но как узнать какая версия react-redux подоходит, а также версия redux-toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit react-redux --legacy-peer-deps
```

Может кому-нибудь пригодится.